# What does standard deviation mean in simple terms?

Tags: standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics

There are multiple sources to answer the above question. For example [here](https://jdmeducational.com/what-does-standard-deviation-tell-us-4-things-to-know/) it says

> Standard deviation tells us about the variability of values in a data
> set. It is a measure of dispersion, showing how spread out the data
> points are around the mean.

So far so good, but I would like a clearer explanation with an example.

For example I have a list of 65 values and when I calculate their average and std I got

```
Average:
8.046153846153846
Std:
3.684557169927145
```

and I got a plot

[image: plot]

By looking at the plot we can see that it is almost always the value 10 but sometimes it varies.

In this situation what does the data 3.68 (the std) give to understand the situation? And is there a better statistic to understand what is happening to the set?

Comment: What do you mean by calculating standard deviations of individual values? You need multiple datapoints to calculate it. It's not clear what does your plot show.

Comment: There are many questions on site that address the meaning of standard deviation. Start with the "Related" column in the sidebar on the right (some of which should have been offered to you when you posted); and then try some searches.  Your plot shows pretty clear indication of serial dependence (with periods of low/0 variance) and periods of greater variation. This feature is important to describing what's happening with your data.

Comment: @Tim There are multiple values (datapoints) as you can see from the plot. A list of  60 something values

Comment: Then standard deviation should be a single value summarizing the values. What does the plot show?

Comment: You can find over a thousand posts about [interpreting standard deviation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=standard+deviation+interp*) here on CV, so I'm confident that a few minutes spent exploring them will answer your question.

Answer (score 6):

It is quite clear from the plot that the data consist of integer values between 0 and 11 and the most frequent values are 0 and 10. Intermediate values are quite infrequent. Knowing how the data was generated would probably explain why the data is almost dichotomous.

The most informative initial summary of the data would simply be a table of how often each value appears. In R, the table would be created by

```
table(x)
```

Computing the mean and standard deviation for such data is of little interpretative value.